# Converting and rescaling a lot of png images to jpeg

Tags: scripting, conversion, images

I have a lot of .png images in a folder. Is there a command (or software) that can convert all them to .jpg and (simultaneously) rescale the created .jpg files to 25% of their original size?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/):

```
convert x.png -resize 25% x.jpg
```

will create a 25%-scaled JPEG version of `x.png`.

To do all the PNG files at once, use a `for` loop:

```
for filename in *.png ; do convert "$filename" -resize 25% "${filename%.png}.jpg" ; done
```

We look at every file matching `*.png`, and for each one run the `convert` command above. `"${filename%.png}.jpg"` generates the `.jpg` filename for each `.png`: it removes the extension [with `%`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and puts `.jpg` back on the end.

Comment: Also:
`ls *.png | cut -d'.' -f1 | xargs -I {} convert {}.png -resize 25% {}.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `mogrify` to batch convert & resize all `.png` images in the current directory:

```
mogrify -resize 25% -format jpg *.png
```

because it uses `-format jpg` the original `.png` images are left untouched
(when `format` is the same or missing the originals are overwritten).